# "On Delete Cascade" if deleting a row from the child table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sqlcommand, cascading-deletes

I'm having a difficult time understanding "on delete cascade"
If I had the following example:

create table X (id int primary key, name char(10));

create table Y (bid int primary key, aid references A(id) on delete cascade);

X contains one row (111, 'Mike')

Y contains two rows (1000, 111), (2000, 111)**

I if removed row (2000,111) in table Y what would happen?

Would that row just be deleted or would it even allow me to delete anything because of the reference to the parent table?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be deleted and nothing else would happen. Cascading deletes only go from the referenced table to the referencing table.
So a delete on table X will cascade a delete down to table y, while a delete on table y has no impact on table x.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will happen, only if you delete a row from table X the rows in table Y referencing it will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

ON Delete cascade option wont effect anything if you perform any delete on the child table. This option is used to specify, when you delete a row in the parent table, the database server also deletes any rows associated with that row (foreign keys) in a child table. The principal advantage to the cascading-deletes feature is that it allows you to reduce the quantity of SQL statements you need to perform delete actions.